# Nth Fibonacci using pointers in C; recursive and array

Tags: c, fibonacci

I have this code so far. It works and does what I want it to. I'm wondering if I could make it better. I do not really care for user input or any other "finish touches," just want to make the code more efficient and maybe more useful for future projects.
Excessive comments are for my personal use, I find it easier to read when I go back to old projects for references and what not. 
Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void fabonacci(int * fibArr,int numberOfSeries){
    int n;

    //allocate memory size
    fibArr = malloc (sizeof(int) * numberOfSeries);
    //first val, fib = 0
    *fibArr = 0;//100
    fibArr++;
    //second val, fib = 1
    *fibArr = 1;//104
    fibArr++;

    //printing first two fib values 0 and 1
    printf("%i\n%i\n", *(fibArr- 2),*(fibArr- 1));

    //loop for fib arr
    for(n=0;n<numberOfSeries -2;n++,fibArr++){
        //108 looking back at 104 looking back at 100
        //112 looking back at 108 looking back at 104
        *fibArr = *(fibArr-1) + *(fibArr -2);
        //printing fib arr
        printf("%i\n", *fibArr);
    }
}

int main(){
    //can implm user input if want
    int n = 10;
    int *fib;

    //calling 
    fabonacci(fib,n);
}
```

Comment: first thing I see - you have memory leak, as you don't free `fibArr`

Comment: When you do `fibArr++` you *lose* the original pointer. Furthermore, the variable is a *local* variable inside the function, which means its value is copied and all assignments you make to it (like `fibArr = malloc(...)`) are lost when the function returns.

Comment: UB probably shouldn’t happen when `numberOfSeries` is 1 or 0.

Comment: What's the goal here? Print each element up to n or create an array of n fibonacci numbers?

Comment: regard: "//printing first two fib values 0 and 1"  the first two fibonacci series numbers are 1 and 1,  NOT 0 and 1

Comment: the posted code results in a memory leak!  This is because the allocated memory is never passed to `free()`

Comment: @user3629249 "First value of fibonacci is 0. The [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is defined with seed values fib(0) = 0 and fib(1) = 1. This is a requirement for the rest of the sequence to be correct. The only condition under which fib(0) = 1 could work is if you defined a "-1 based counting system" (as opposed to the usual conventions of 0-based and 1-based). This would be pretty wacky however, I'm sure you agree" ~ answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/44389/noldorin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is halfway between two possible interpretations and I can't tell which one you meant. If you want `fibonacci(n)` to just give the `n`th number and not have any external side effects, you should write it as follows:

```
int fibonacci(int n) {
   int lo, hi;
   lo = 0;
   hi = 1;
   while(n-- > 0) {
     int tmp = hi;
     lo = hi;
     hi = lo + tmp;
   }
   return lo;
}
```

You need no `malloc`s or `free`s because this takes constant, stack-allocated space.

If you want, instead, to store the entire sequence in memory as you compute it, you may as well require that the memory already be allocated, because this allows the caller to control where the numbers go.

```
// n < 0 => undefined behavior
// not enough space allocated for (n + 1) ints in res => undefined behavior
void fibonacci(int *res, int n) {
  res[0] = 0;
  if(n == 0) { return; }
  res[1] = 1;
  if(n == 1) { return; }
  for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    res[i] = res[i-1] + res[i-2];
  }
}
```

It is now the caller's job to allocate memory:

```
int main(){
  int fib[10]; // room for F_0 to F_9
  fibonacci(fib, 9); // fill up to F_9

  int n = ...; // some unknown number
  int *fib2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 2)); // room for (n + 2) values
  if(fib2 == NULL) { /* error handling */ }
  fibonacci(fib2 + 1, n); // leave 1 space at the start for other purposes.
  // e.g. you may want to store the length into the first element
  fib2[0] = n + 1;
  // this fibonacci is more flexible than before
  // remember to free it
  free(fib2);
}
```

And you can wrap this to allocate space itself while still leaving the more flexible version around:

```
int *fibonacci_alloc(int n) {
    int *fib = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 1));
    if(fib == NULL) { return NULL; }
    fibonacci(fib, n);
    return fib;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not good at pointers and your answer showed a lot. Great comments, makes super easy to follow.

Comment: the first two numbers of the fibonacci sequence are 1 and 1, NOT 0 and 1,  so this answer is 'good', but makes an incorrect assumption about those first two values

Comment: @user3629249 [Wikipedia disagrees with you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: @HTNW I started with [this](http://textuploader.com/dhuux) code and wanted to rewrite it using pointers. Maybe that's why it seems confusing what I was doing.

Comment: here is the [wikipedia-Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) link.  It states that the original Fibonacci sequence started at 1, however, some people now want to start it at 0.  (0 times the current evaluation is 0 and usually not a value of interest.)  Note:  Back when I was in school, the Fibonacci sequence only started with 1

Comment: @user3629249 In my assignments and books fib start with 0. You should not take it so hard.

Answer (score -1):

One way to improve the code is to let the caller create the array, and pass the array to the `fibonacci` function. That eliminates the need for `fibonacci` to allocate memory. Note that the caller can allocate/free if desired, or the caller can just declare an array.

The other improvement is to use array notation inside of the `fibonacci` function. You may be thinking that the pointer solution has better performance. It doesn't matter. The maximum value for `n` is 47 before you overflow a 32-bit `int`, so `n` is not nearly big enough for performance to be a consideration.

Finally, the `fibonacci` function should protect itself from bad values of `n`. For example, if `n` is 1, then the function should put a 0 in the first array entry, and not touch any other entries.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fibonacci(int *array, int length)
{
    if (length > 0)
        array[0] = 0;
    if (length > 1)
        array[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < length; i++)
        array[i] = array[i-1] + array[i-2];
}

int main(void)
{
    int fib[47];
    int n = sizeof(fib) / sizeof(fib[0]);

    fibonacci(fib, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("fib[%d] = %d\n", i, fib[i]);
}
```